# Create a set of keys for an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

So I make an API call. This generates an array with dynamic number of elements. I want to add additional empty keys until the number of elements reach 50 (api call will always be lesser than 50). What is the easiest way to do this? Currently I am doing:

```
$dataArray = $this->APICall();
$toAdd = 50 - count($dataArray);
for($x=$toAdd;$x<=50;$x++)
{
  $dataArray[$x] = "";
}
```

I wanted to check if there is an easier, perhaps single-line way of doing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is function `array_fill` that you can use to fill array with spaces to size of 50. And then merge it with initial array.

Documentation for `array_fill` is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

```
$dataArray = array_merge($dataArray, array_fill(count($dataArray), 50 - count($dataArray), ""));
```

Comment: Please put some more details to make your answer clear for people